# Summation of infinite series with product of denominator factors in AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Evaluate $$\sum_{n=8}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-4)(n-2)n(n+2)(n+4)}$$

I tried using partial fractions but very cumbersome. I just need hint only.

Comment: Note that $$\frac1{(n-4)(n-2)n(n+2)(n+4)}=x_n-x_{n+2}$$ with $$x_n=\frac{1}{8(n-4)(n-2)n(n+2)}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT :
The required summation is $$\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=8}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n-4)(n-2)n(n+2)} - \frac{1}{(n-2)n(n+2)(n+4)}\right)$$

Comment: amazing thanks a ton